# XmlTextWriter incorrectly writing control characters

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmltextwriter, control-characters

.NET's `XmlTextWriter` creates invalid xml files.

In XML, some control characters are allowed, like 'horizontal tab' (`&#x9;`), but others are not, like 'vertical tab' (`&#xB;`). (See [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/#charsets).)

I have a string which contains a UTF-8 control character that is not allowed in XML.
Although `XmlTextWriter` escapes the character, the resulting XML is ofcourse still invalid.

How can I make sure that `XmlTextWriter` never produces an illegal XML file?

Or, if it's not possible to do this with `XmlTextWriter`, how can I strip the specific control characters that aren't allowed in XML from a string?

Example code:

```
using (XmlTextWriter writer =
  new XmlTextWriter("test.xml", Encoding.UTF8))
{
  writer.WriteStartDocument();
  writer.WriteStartElement("Test");
  writer.WriteValue("hello \xb world");
  writer.WriteEndElement();
  writer.WriteEndDocument();
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Test>hello &#xB; world</Test>
```

Comment: You can't have an escaped vertical tab in XML? Could you reference the standard?

Comment: @Jodrell That's right, you can't. XML is for text, not for control characters or binary data. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This documentation of a behaviour is hidden in the [documentation of the WriteString method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestring.aspx) but it sounds like it applies to the whole class.

> The default behavior of an XmlWriter created using Create is to throw
>   an ArgumentException when attempting to write character values in the
>   range 0x-0x1F (excluding white space characters 0x9, 0xA, and 0xD).
>   These invalid XML characters can be written by creating the XmlWriter
>   with the CheckCharacters property set to false. Doing so will result
>   in the characters being replaced with numeric character entities (`&#0;`
>   through `&#0x1F`). Additionally, an XmlTextWriter created with the new
>   operator will replace the invalid characters with numeric character
>   entities by default.

So it seems that you end up writing invalid characters because you are using the XmlTextWriter class. A better solution for you would be to use the [XmlWriter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y8188ze.aspx) instead.

Comment: It's a bit weird, but apparently even though the `XmlTextWriter` constructor exists, you're not supposed to use it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz7cs0d.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Just found this question when I was struggling with the same issue and I ended up solving it with an regex:

```
return Regex.Replace(s, @"[\u0000-\u0008\u000B\u000C\u000E-\u001F]", "");
```

Hope it helps someone as an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Built in .NET escapers such as `SecurityElement.Escape` don't properly escape/strip it either.

- You could set `CheckCharacters` to `false` on both the writer and the reader if your application is the only one interacting with the file. The resulting XML file would still be technically **invalid** though.

See:

```
XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
xmlWriterSettings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
xmlWriterSettings.CheckCharacters = false;
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var w = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xmlWriterSettings);
w.WriteStartDocument();
w.WriteStartElement("Test");
w.WriteString("hello \xb world");
w.WriteEndElement();
w.WriteEndDocument();
w.Close();
var xml = sb.ToString();
```

- If setting `CheckCharacters` to `true`(which it is by default) is a bit too strict since it will simply throw an exception an alternative approach that's more lenient to invalid XML characters would be to just strip them:

Googling a bit yielded the whitelist [XmlTextEncoder](https://github.com/mkropat/.NET-Snippets/blob/master/XmlTextEncoder.cs) however it'll also remove `DEL` and others in the range U+007F–U+0084, U+0086–U+009F that according to [Valid XML Characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML) on wikipedia are only valid in certain contexts and which the RFC mentions as discouraged but still valid characters.

```
public static class XmlTextExtentions
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<char, string> textEntities = new Dictionary<char, string> {
        { '&', "&amp;"}, { '<', "&lt;" }, { '>', "&gt;" }, 
        { '"', "&quot;" }, { '\'', "&apos;" }
    };
    public static string ToValidXmlString(this string str)
    {
        var stripped = str
            .Select((c,i) => new 
            { 
                c1 = c, 
                c2 = i + 1 < str.Length ? str[i+1]: default(char),
                v = XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(c),
                p = i + 1 < str.Length ? XmlConvert.IsXmlSurrogatePair(str[i + 1], c) : false,
                pp = i > 0 ? XmlConvert.IsXmlSurrogatePair(c, str[i - 1]) : false
            })
            .Aggregate("", (s, c) => {                  
                if (c.pp)
                    return s;
                if (textEntities.ContainsKey(c.c1))
                    s += textEntities[c.c1];
                else if (c.v)
                    s += c.c1.ToString();
                else if (c.p)
                    s += c.c1.ToString() + c.c2.ToString();
                return s;
            });
        return stripped;
    }
}
```

This passes all the XmlTextEncoder tests except for the one that expects it to strip `DEL` which `XmlConvert.IsXmlChar`, Wikipedia, and the spec marks as a valid (although discouraged) character.