# Why vertical tab is not escaped by ElementTree in python 3.5?

Tags: python, xml

I'm converting some text data to xml and use `xml.etree.ElementTree` to do so. Also I need to output pretty xml so I use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1206856/1948038).

But my data contains some strange symbols like vertical tab (`\v` or `\x0b`). And when I convert my xml to string it is not escaped (which I suppose produces invalid xml) and then when I try to reparse it to pretty print it fails.

Here is the code example

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xml.dom.minidom as MD

root = ET.Element("root")
root.text = "some <<>> text \v other text"

rough_string = ET.tostring(root, 'utf-8')
reparsed = MD.parseString(rough_string)
```

Here `rough_string` contains following `<root>some &lt;&lt;&gt;&gt; text  other text</root>`. It did escape the <<>> but missed the \v.

While if I do same on .NET it do escape it

```cs
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();    
XmlElement priceElement = doc.CreateElement("root");
priceElement.InnerText = "some <<>> text \v other text";
doc.AppendChild(priceElement);  
string res = doc.OuterXml;
```

Result is `<root>some &lt;&lt;&gt;&gt; text &#xB; other text</root>`.

Is this a bug in ElementTree? How can I solve this issue?

UPDATE: Seems that the behavior of both ElementTree and .NET [is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386970/best-practice-for-handling-vertical-tabs-and-other-invalid-xml-characters) as was pointed in comments. But how should I handle this? If these are some really tricky chars I could just remove them from the source string (I do not have very strict requirements for this), but I need to know the full list of such chars, where could I find one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25926644/1030675

Comment: I can assume that there might be some illegal chars, but this should be somehow handled? .NET does handle it somehow? How can I handle it in python?

Comment: .NET handles it wrongly, the entity `&#xB;` doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, but what is the correct way to handle it? Does the fact that this symbol is included in the output of ElementTree is also an incorrect behavior?

Comment: Whether it's "incorrect" depends on the specification: because such checking is expensive, it's quite legitimate for an API to say "we don't check that the string contains only valid XML characters, this is the caller's responsibility".

Answer (score 0):

If you can't be sure about text content, you should enclose it in a CDATA section. Unfortunately, the plain `\v` is not accepted even inside a CDATA so you have two options

- Remove it or replace it with space
- Encoding as `&#xB;`seems to work at list for a libxml2 utility (see example at bottom of answer). For python, [lxml is based on libxml2](http://lxml.de/compatibility.html) too.

  ```
  echo -e "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><root><a><\041[CDATA[asdf\ndf \v nbbv]]></a></root>" | xmllint --format -
  ```

Result with error:

```
-:2: parser error : CData section not finished
asdf
d
df 
    nbbv]]></a></root>
^
-:2: parser error : PCDATA invalid Char value 11
df 
    nbbv]]></a></root>
^
-:2: parser error : Sequence ']]>' not allowed in content
df 
    nbbv]]></a></root>
    ^
-:2: parser error : Sequence ']]>' not allowed in content
df 
    nbbv]]></a></root>
        ^
-:2: parser error : internal error: detected an error in element content

df 
    nbbv]]></a></root>
        ^
```

Replacing with its HTML entity

```
echo -e "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><root><a><\041[CDATA[asdf\ndf &#xB; nbbv]]></a></root>" | xmllint --format -
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<a><![CDATA[asdf
df &#xB; nbbv]]></a>
</root>
```